# Symfony2: How to restrict / deny access to certain routes by IP address?

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle, access-control

I'd like to disallow access to `/login` and `/register` if a client's IP address has been banned.

The (black-) list of banned IPs is stored in the database.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since symfony 2.4 you can use the [Expression Language Component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/expression_language/introduction.html) in your config-files.

Now implementing a simple IP check is easy:

- create a service (i.e. `access_manager`) with a method (i.e. `getBannedIPs()`) that fetches the list of banned IPs from your storage layer
- Add an expression to your security configuration that compares the returned array against the client's IP address
- That's it.

### example

```
# app/config/security.yml
security:
    # ...
    access_control:
        - path: ^/(login|register)$
          allow_if: "request.getClientIp() not in @=service('access_manager').getBannedIPs()"
```

Comment: You are right, but how do I do if I want to inform the user with a message?

Comment: I tried to provide the simplest solution ... but for this advanced case you'd have to add a `kernel.request` listener that matches the IP and adds the flashmessage to the session flashbag ... or just be a bit tricky with a ternary operator and a condition that adds the flashmessage and always returns true ....  `( request.getClientIp() not in @=service('access_manager').getBannedIPs() ) ? ( @=service('session').getFlashBag().add('warning', 'You have been banned.') != false ) : false`. Got the idea?

Comment: Yes thanks! I never used expressions until now but I'll start to play with them to discover their use limits and where they can be better or simplets then other solutions.

Comment: I've tried this solution but I get error `Unexpected character "@"` in the security.yml

Answer (score 2):

### Use controllers events (preferred)

You can subscribe to events on registration controller.

For registration, you can subscribe to `REGISTRATION_INITIALIZE` event.

Here is the doc for [controller events](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/controller_events.md).

### Overriding controller methods

The second solution is to [override login and register controller methods](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/overriding_controllers.md) but you will have to duplicate all code of the login/register action.

Comment: There is no need for an event listener or controller overrides to solve this. Just make use of the expression language component under  `access_control` within **security.yml**. See my answer :)