# Unexpected character "@" around position

Tags: php, symfony

I would like to create white list ips, that can connect to my api.
Try to use [Expression Language Component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/expression_language/introduction.html)
But when I try add rule to security.yml

```
    - path: ^/v2/api
      allow_if: "request.getClientIp() in @=service('app.white_list_manager').getWhiteList()"
```

I have an error:

> SyntaxError in Lexer.php line 90:
>   Unexpected character "@" around position 25 for expression request.getClientIp() in @=service('app.white_list_manager').getWhiteList().

How I can solve it?
Symfony version 3.0.9

Comment: are you sure it is even possible to use ExpressionLanguage in the security.yml config ?   and not only in properties, as arguments with configurator and as arguments to calls (method calls).    as here -> http://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/expression_language.html

Comment: I use answer from this question 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29316277/symfony2-how-to-restrict-deny-access-to-certain-routes-by-ip-address

Comment: yes, and even though it was marked as answer by a few, it did not even help the original poster which asked the question ..

Comment: solved with kernel listener. Thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One workaround would be :

to simple define a listener that listens to `kernel.request`, inject your `"@app.white_list_manager"` and the `"@request_stack"`.

Then check what route you are on, and check the ip in the whitelistmanager, and act accordingly. (redirect, deny access, whatever)